# Use Linux network namespace to map one IP range to another

Tags: network-namespace

I have two nic interfaces having the same address range, 192.168.10.0/24. A host application has to distinguish between the two subnets. Mapping IP ranges seems like an ideal solution. The subnets can have any number of devices. Devices are likely to be occasionally swapped out. Subnets shall not have access to internet.

I wish to setup a Linux network namespace that maps IP address 192.168.11.0/24 on the namespace to a nic interface inside the namespace having IP address 192.168.10.0/24.

As you can see from the script below, I've tried various routing rules, many commented out, without success.

```
##################################################################

# setup ip forwarding
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo modprobe 8021q

# create the namespace p1
sudo ip netns add p1

# create a veth pair
sudo ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1

# move veth1 to p1
sudo ip link set veth1 netns p1

# configure the host IP address
sudo ip addr add 192.168.11.1/24 dev veth0
sudo ip link set veth0 up

# Sometimes get ARP requests. Give it a pseudo mac address?
# sudo arp -s 192.168.11.10 08:E4:66:A5:2E:33

# inside the namespace
sudo ip netns exec p1 ip addr add 192.168.11.2/24 dev veth1
sudo ip netns exec p1 ip link set veth1 up
sudo ip netns exec p1 ip link set lo up

# add the nic
sudo ip link set enp2s0f0 down
sudo ip link set enp2s0f0 netns p1
sudo ip netns exec p1 ip addr add 192.168.10.1/24 dev enp2s0f0
sudo ip netns exec p1 ip link set enp2s0f0 up
sudo ip netns exec p1 ip route add default via 192.168.10.1

sudo ip netns exec p1 sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

#-delete-# sudo ip netns exec p1 iptables -A FORWARD -i veth1 -o enp2s0f0 -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo ip netns exec p1 iptables -A FORWARD -i veth1 -o enp2s0f0 -p tcp --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT


sudo ip netns exec p1 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0f0 -j MASQUERADE

#-old-# sudo ip netns exec p1 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.11.10 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.10
#-old-# sudo ip netns exec p1 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d 192.168.11.10 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.10
#-old-# 
#-old-# sudo ip netns exec p1 iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.10.10 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#-# sudo ip netns exec p1 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s 192.168.10.10 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.11.10
#-# sudo ip netns exec p1 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -s 192.168.10.10 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.11.10


#-# # Set up DNAT to map 192.168.11.10 to 192.168.10.10
#-# sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.11.10 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.10
#-# sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.10 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.11.10

#-# sudo ip addr add 192.168.11.10/24 dev veth0

# Add default route in the p1 namespace
#-# sudo ip netns exec p1 ip route add default via 192.168.10.2

##################################################################
```

Comment: what is the business related question or issue in here?

Comment: This sounds like the XY problem. Leaving aside the question of whether the approach is in any way valid, there's also a question of how your host is currently handling 2 interfaces on the same subnet (IME Centos 5 would happily handle this out of the box, but, e.g. Ubuntu 18.04 would end up with asymmetric routing and dropping nearly all packets). To achieve the result you're asking for, I believe you'd need to amend the routes both inside and outside the namespace setting the local subnet using 'via' the appropriate interface.